# CentOS 7 SDDM can't click GUI with mouse

Tags: x11, display-manager, sddm

I ran a fresh **Minimal** install of Cent OS 7.  When finished, I run this command to get the GUI setup:

```
yum -y install epel-release;yum update -y;yum groupinstall "Xfce" -y;yum -y groupinstall X11;echo "exec /usr/bin/xfce4-session" >> ~/.xinitrc;sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target;systemctl isolate graphical.target;yum -y install sddm; systemctl stop gdm.service; systemctl disable gdm.service; systemctl enable sddm.service
```

Reboot, Login, **SDDM** is really finicky.  At first I can click on a xfce4 launcher to launch terminal, after that I can't **drag/resize** the window with the mouse, I can't **close/maximize/minimize** with the **mouse**.  I think the problem has to do with **what window is in focus**.  For example, if I click in the **black space** of the **terminal window**, Now I can only click inside the terminal space and nowhere else.  If I try to **hover my mouse** over the Icons, they **don't light up**.  The only way to get out of the terminal window is to right-click the black space in the terminal window which **brings up the context menu**.  When the context menu is brought up, I can then **click on anything I want** (because now the context menu has focus which somehow fixes it).  If I click in the black space in the terminal window, the problem repeats.

Here is what fixes the problem until reboot:

```
systemctl restart ssdm.service
```

If I run that command, re-login, its fixed until reboot.

So either:

A.  I need the proper fix. (I prefer this method please)

B.  I need a way to run this command on boot.

**Additional Info:**

```
systemctl status sddm.service
```

> Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/sddm.service; enabled; vendor
>   preset: disabled)    Active: active (running) since Wed 2019-03-06
>   21:46:40 CST; 13h ago
>        Docs: man:sddm(1)
>              man:sddm.conf(5)  Main PID: 5410 (sddm)    CGroup: /system.slice/sddm.service
>              ├─5410 /usr/bin/sddm
>              └─5444 /usr/bin/X -nolisten tcp -auth /var/run/sddm/{1c6b25a2-4aa9-47de-b502-2f6d5333000a} -background none
>   -noreset -displayfd 17 vt1

```
systemctl status gdm.service
```

> gdm.service - GNOME Display Manager
>      Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/gdm.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
>      Active: inactive (dead)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is I needed **startx** to run after login.  Since I am running XFCE, I have available to me "Session and Startup".  Start>Settings>Session and Startup.  Add command:

```
startx
```

To add using command line:

```
mkdir ~/.config/autostart
touch ~/.config/autostart/startx.desktop
echo -e "[Desktop Entry]\nEncoding=UTF-8\nVersion=0.9.4\nType=Application\nName=startx\nComment=startx\nExec=startx\nOnlyShowIn=XFCE;\nStartupNotify=false\nTerminal=false\nHidden=false" > ~/.config/autostart/startx.desktop
```

This is probably not the cleanest way to do it because the screen flashes... other than that works perfect.